# "Collacea" è un derivato dalla parola "colla"?

Tags: word-meaning

Dal libro di Elena Ferrante *Storia della bambina perduta*.  La frase:

> [...] e lei sprofondava in una realtà pasticciata, **collacea**, senza riuscire a dare contorni nitidi alle sensazioni.

Ho cercato dappertutto, anche su Google, e solamente trovo citazioni dai suoi libri, ma nessuna spiegazione del significato di "collacea".

È possibile che sia un derivato dalla parola "colla"? Voglio dire, la parola descrive una qualità, una consistenza come quella di una colla semiliquida? Mi sembra che Ferrante voglia dire qualcosa che si scioglie.

Mille grazie.

Comment: Curiosamente, appare in [questo documento](http://bollettino.aib.it/index.php/boll/issue/viewFile/772/48), che non ha niente a che vedere con la Ferrante: "La
carta sfibrata necessita di un delicato lavoro che restituisca al foglio le
sostanze collacee perdute e lo renda di nuovo consistente".

Answer (score 4):

La tua supposizione è esatta, il senso è proprio quello da te descritto, ovvero descrive una consistenza simile alla colla, appiccicosa.

Il suffisso *-ceo* trasforma in questo caso un sostantivo (colla) in un aggettivo; si parla di **morfema aggettivatore** come viene descritto in [questo elenco](http://wwwdata.unibg.it/dati/corsi/24169/60754-Lista_morfemi_italiano_Facchi.pdf):

> AGGETTIVATORI: trasformano un nome o un verbo in un aggettivo.   
>   - -ace-: suffisso aggettivatore con valore di “prodotto/derivato da N”.
>
> carta → cartaceo 
>   legno → legnaceo 
>   erba → erbaceo  
>   sebo → sebaceo

Curiosamente cercando su Google "collaceo" [trovo addirittura un esempio risalente al 1770](https://books.google.it/books?id=DURcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=collaceo&source=bl&ots=HXgrlzHjDJ&sig=ACfU3U1ULXbeVh_htUw743zQjveMZtCUUg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOt42a5ODpAhWE2qQKHY0LDQUQ6AEwBHoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=collaceo&f=false).

Comment: Ottimo!    Ammetto che non ho cercato collaceo, ma solamente collacea.  Mille grazie per la spiegazione sugli aggettivatori!